# How to implement a script folder to a Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I have bought a script with a boostrap base. The folder has this structure:

```
csgoboost
├── css/
├── fonts/
├── img/
├── js/
└── index.php
```

Should I just put it in the Public_HTML folder and declare it on a webpage? I want to run it on one specific webpage, it is basically a form where you can select different options. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register and enqueue the script so WordPress knows what it's called and where to find it like so:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_home_path() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

This would work if the js folder is in the root directory where you installed WordPress. You can put it in functions.php.

Comment: If I put it in functions.php, how can I ensure that it displays on the specific page I want it to? Thank you

Comment: I added it and I got a fatal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_home_path()

Comment: Ah that means it isn't loaded yet. Can you include require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php'); at the top of functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can put either in a root or in a theme folder.

If you put it into root and want to include any files then use **base_url()** and if you have put script folder into theme then use **get_template_directory_uri()** function to retrieve files.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use css by `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri ();?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
 and  script by

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri ();?>/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Same for images you just need to match path after `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri ();?>`